A question about local trivializations of hermitian vector bundles
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $\pi \colon E \to M$ a smooth vector bundle with a smoothly varying inner product. Is it then always possible to find smooth local trivializations $(U, \varphi \colon \pi^{-1}(U) \to U \times \mathbb{R}^n)$ such that on each fiber $\varphi$ is a unitary map between the fiber of $E$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ with its standard inner product?
It is clear to me that such a map $\varphi$ is easily constructed, but it is not clear that it is smooth. However, I think it should be smooth, and that it is related to the existence of local smooth orthonormal frames.

Doesn't the smooth local orthonormal frame trivially give you a unitary map?

Yes I agree, but with this construction too I don't immediately see that it is smooth. Do you have an easy way to see it?

I think I see it now, constructing $\varphi^{-1}$ from the smooth sections is obviously smooth. Thank you.
